# ggplot2 how to superimpose markers on a single facet?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a ggplot with `geom_line()` facets, but I would like some facets to have markers superimposed on the data. Current code example:

```
sig.1 <- c(rep(c(rep(0,9),2,4,7,10,7,4,2),3),rep(0,7))
sig.2 <- c(rep(c(rep(0,12),10,rep(0,3)),3),rep(0,7))
sig.2.markers <- sig.2*1.2
sig.2.markers[which(sig.2 == 0)] <- NA

df <- data.frame(time=seq(1, length(sig.1)), sig.1, sig.2, sig.2.markers)

df.melt <- melt(df,id='time',variable.name='signal')

# goal: graph with two facets
ggplot(df.melt, aes(x=time, y=value, colour=factor(signal))) + 
    facet_wrap(~signal, ncol=1) +
    scale_color_manual(values=c('blue','black','red')) +
   theme(legend.position = 'none')+
    geom_line()

# facet 2 should look like this with markers superimposed 
ggplot(df, aes(x=time, y=sig.2)) + geom_line() +
        geom_point(aes(x=time, y=sig.2.markers), shape=25, fill="red", size=5, na.rm=TRUE)
```

And the output:

[image: facet graph]

but I want the second facet to have markers superimposed (i.e. `sig.2.markers`) like this:

[image: facet markers]

so there would only be two total facets. Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify different `data =` parameters to any `geom_`, so one common way to do what you want is to have the `_line` geom take all the data and then make a separate data frame for the `_point` geom with the necessary facet column and only populate the one facet:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

sig.1 <- c(rep(c(rep(0,9),2,4,7,10,7,4,2),3),rep(0,7))
sig.2 <- c(rep(c(rep(0,12),10,rep(0,3)),3),rep(0,7))

sig.2.markers <- sig.2*1.2
sig.2.markers[which(sig.2 == 0)] <- NA

df <- data.frame(time=seq(1, length(sig.1)), sig.1, sig.2)

df.melt <- melt(df, id='time', variable.name='signal')

ggplot() + 
  geom_line(
    data = df.melt, 
    aes(x=time, y=value, colour=factor(signal))
  ) +
  geom_point(
    data = data.frame(
      time = which(!is.na(sig.2.markers)),
      sig.2.markers = sig.2.markers[which(!is.na(sig.2.markers))],
      signal = "sig.2"
    ),
    aes(time, sig.2.markers), shape=25, fill="red", size=5, na.rm=TRUE
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~signal, ncol=1) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c('blue','black','red')) +
  theme(legend.position = 'none')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! works great. And I see I don't need to pad the markers with NAs to be the same vector size as the other time series.